# Ros2 Foxy fails installing in Ubuntu 20.10 arm64 following the official documentation

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying for the last 3 days to install Ros2 Foxy (ros2-foxy-20201211-linux-focal-arm64.tar.bz2) in a freshly installed Ubuntu 20.10 arm64 running in a Raspberry Pi 4.
Following the official documentation: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Linux-Install-Binary/ I'm hitting several issues (in order following the official documentation steps):

**1. Missing Groovy release**

`$> sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture)] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list'`

`$> sudo apt update`

`Err:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu groovy Release    404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]`

I can fix this issue changing `groovy` to `focal` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list`

**2. Missing Ros dependencies**

`$> rosdep install --from-paths ros2-linux/share --ignore-src --rosdistro foxy -y --skip-keys "console_bridge fastcdr fastrtps osrf_testing_tools_cpp poco_vendor rmw_connext_cpp rosidl_typesupport_connext_c rosidl_typesupport_connext_cpp rti-connext-dds-5.3.1 tinyxml_vendor tinyxml2_vendor urdfdom urdfdom_headers"`

`ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies: launch: No definition of [python3-lark-parser] for OS version [groovy] rosidl_parser: No definition of [python3-lark-parser] for OS version [groovy] ros2doctor: No definition of [python3-ifcfg] for OS version [groovy] rmw_cyclonedds_cpp: No definition of [cyclonedds] for OS version [groovy]`

Again I can solve this forcing os in `rosdep` with `--os ubuntu:focal`

**2. Missing libraries**

`$> ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker`

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::RCLError' what():  failed to initialize rcl init options: failed to load shared library of rmw implementation: /home/ubuntu/ros2_foxy/ros2-linux/lib/librmw_fastrtps_cpp.so Exception: LoadLibrary error: libtinyxml2.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, at /home/jenkins-agent/workspace/ci_packaging_linux-aarch64/ws/src/ros2/rcutils/src/shared_library.c:84, at /home/jenkins-agent/workspace/ci_packaging_linux-aarch64/ws/src/ros2/rmw_implementation/rmw_implementation/src/functions.cpp:62, at /home/jenkins-agent/workspace/ci_packaging_linux-aarch64/ws/src/ros2/rcl/rcl/src/rcl/init_options.c:61`

---

I tried as well the debian package installation instructions without success: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Linux-Install-Debians/

I need some help to find a solution for a working installation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372225/ros2-foxy-fails-installing-in-ubuntu-20.10-arm64-following-the-official-documentation/) by [veilkrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/39879/veilkrand/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps already known, but officially, Foxy only supports Ubuntu Focal (`20.04`): [REP 2000: ROS 2 Releases and Target Platforms - Foxy Fitzroy (May 2020 - May 2023)](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#foxy-fitzroy-may-2020-may-2023).

The official documentation you link is fairly clear about this:

> We support Ubuntu Linux Focal Fossa (20.04) 64-bit x86 and 64-bit ARM.

From the [System Requirements](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Linux-Install-Binary/#system-requirements) section.

> Missing Groovy release [..] I can fix this issue changing `groovy` to `focal` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list`

this isn't really a "fix": that would make `apt` install binaries compiled against Ubuntu Focal on Ubuntu Groovy.

There's a good chance this is the cause of your problems.

If it works, there's no guarantee it's going to be stable, as mixing-and-matching libraries of different versions is a good way to make an instable system.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mam](https://answers.ros.org/users/28637/mam/) on 2021-04-18**:
that cause me a lot of crashes and problems

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-18**:
What caused crashes?